Data serialization not mapping variables
My code is supposed to make an weather API call and store the data into data classes using serialization, however the data in the Log is null. When I remove the serial names and just name the variable the exact same as the serial name, it works correctly.
Retrofit:
object RetrofitInstance {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.open-meteo.com/"

    val instance: WeatherAPI by lazy {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RetrofitInstance.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        retrofit.create(WeatherAPI::class.java)
    }
}

API Call and data storage:
api.getWeatherData(
             location.latitude,
             location.longitude,
            "temperature_2m,relative_humidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation,weather_code,wind_speed_10m,wind_direction_10m",
            "visibility",
            "temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,sunrise,sunset,daylight_duration,uv_index_max",
           "auto",
            1
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherResults> { // Change to WeatherResults
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherResults>, response: Response<WeatherResults>) {
                // Provide more detailed error messages based on response code if necessary
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.let {
                        weatherCache.updateCache(it) // Update the weather cache
                        Log.d("API Call", "Full API Response: ${response.body()}")
                        onSuccess(it)
                    } ?: onFailure(Throwable("Response body is null"))
                } else {
                    onFailure(Throwable("Error: ${response.code()}"))
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherResults>, t: Throwable) {
                onFailure(t)
            }
        })

Data classes
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName

@Serializable
data class WeatherResults(
    val current: Current? = null,
    val daily: Daily? = null,
    val hourly: Hourly? = null
)

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName

@Serializable
data class Current(
    @SerialName("temperature_2m") val temperature: Double?,  // Works as expected
    @SerialName("apparent_temperature") val apparentTemperature: Double?,
    @SerialName("relative_humidity_2m") val relativeHumidity: Int?,  // Matches JSON
    @SerialName("weather_code") val weatherCode: Int?,
    @SerialName("wind_speed_10m") val windSpeed: Double?,
    @SerialName("wind_direction_10m") val windDirection: Double?,
    val visibility: Int?,
    val time: String
)

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName


@Serializable
data class Daily(
    val time: List<String?>?,
    @SerialName("weather_code") val weatherCode: List<Int?>?,
    @SerialName("temperature_2m_max") val temperatureMax: List<Double?>?,
    @SerialName("temperature_2m_min") val temperatureMin: List<Double?>?,
    @SerialName("precipitation_probability_max") val precipitationProbability: List<Int?>?,
    @SerialName("apparent_temperature_max") val apparentTemperatureMax: List<Double?>?,
    @SerialName("apparent_temperature_min") val apparentTemperatureMin: List<Double?>?,
    val sunrise: List<String?>?,
    val sunset: List<String?>?,
    @SerialName("sunshine_duration") val sunshineDuration: List<Double?>?,
    @SerialName("uv_index_max") val uvIndexMax: List<Double?>?
)



I have tried removing serialization and just naming the variables accordingly, and the data stores correctly. I have also checked my gradle and the plugin / dependencies are up to date.

Solved, I had to fix my RetrofitInstance class to include JSON parsing

Solved, I had to fix my RetrofitInstance class to include JSON parsing
object RetrofitInstance {

    fun getInstance(): WeatherAPI {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .apply {
                    addConverterFactory(
                        Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
                            .asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType())
                    )
            }
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(WeatherAPI::class.java)
    }
}

